# Run time error 9 VBA

Tags: vba, time

So i'm having a minor problem and might just be blind!

```
Public Sub copy_from_another_sheet_all2()

Dim countrows1 As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\sassrv01-prod\ewpublic\3929ALL\JeppeKNID.xlsx")

countrows1 = wb.Sheets("X-variabel").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X-variabel").Range("A1:R" & countrows1).Value = wb.Sheets("X-variabel").Range("A1:R" & countrows1).Value*
```

Is giving me a run time error 9 - and I have no clue why? If anyone can assist thanks :)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo That's not what the OP is trying to acheive, they want the last row in column A - for which their code on that line is correct. `Row.Count` would result in a compile error

Comment: Can you try to change Integer to Long?

Comment: @MarcoMan ooh now i see it, thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new String variable for range address, I think it should work.

```
Dim addr as String
addr = "A1:R" & countrows1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X-variabel").Range(addr).Value = wb.Sheets("X-variabel").Range(addr).Value
```

But there is another way, which I prefer, and that is using Copy/Paste for this stuff:

```
wb.Sheets("X-variabel").Range("A1:R" & countrows1).Select
Selection.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X-variabel").Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X-variabel").Range("A1:R" & countrows1)
```